# Дубликат функции

Tags: php, функции

Подскажите как сделать уникальное название для функции что-то вроде рандомное название функции.

Дело в том функция работает совместно с парсером сначала парсится текст после идет обработка текста через эту функцию, но если парсить по одной статьи функция нормально функционирует, но если в настройках парсера поставть значение за один приход парсить две и более статьи то начинаются конфликты по поводу дубликатов функции synonimize.

Код такой

```
if(!isset($inform)){

$str = $html;

function synonimize($str, $repl_array){

    $keys = array_map(function($key){

    return '#\b('.$key.')\b#u';

}, $repl_array);

foreach ($keys as $i=>$key) {

    $str = preg_replace_callback($key, function ($match) use ($repl_array, $i) {

        $syns = explode('|', $repl_array[$i]);

        array_splice($syns, array_search(mb_strtolower($match[0]), array_map('mb_strtolower', $syns)), 1);

        return $syns[array_rand($syns)];

   }, $str);

}

return $str;

}

$gb = file("wysiwyg/slov.txt");

$html = synonimize($str,$gb);

}
```

Comment: Изучите параллельное асинхронное программирование , и многозадачность: здесь описано https://phpprofi.ru/blogs/post/100

Answer (score 2):

Ну просто функция создалась раз, второй раз ее создавать не надо:

```
if (!function_exists('synonimize')) {
    function synonimize($str, $repl_array){
        // ...
    }
}
```